# Select all anchors whose parents are not ul[class="nav navbar-nav"] li

Tags: css

would anyone be so kind to tell me what's wrong with the following CSS selector?

```
:not(ul[class="nav navbar-nav"] li) > a
```

I'm trying to select all `anchor` elements whose `parent is not ul[class="nav navbar-nav"] li` Thx in advanced :)

I'm trying to set a CSS property for all anchors except the following ones:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Hi</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Bye</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: The right selector using jQuery would be `jQuery(':not(ul[class="nav navbar-nav"] li) > a')`

Comment: "The right selector using jQuery would be" the exact same selector, just, you know, with jQuery.

Comment: @Vucko: But the question here isn't about multiple arguments to :not(). It's about a single, complex selector argument to :not().

Answer (score 1):

You're better off styling the general first, and then overriding with the specific. Would this suffice:

```css
a {color: red}

ul.nav.navbar-nav > li > a  {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#">Hi</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Hello</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Bye</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href="#">Default Link Style</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, there is no good alternative, really.

Comment: By now, i did something similar to @nvioli proposal but i was wondering about how to accomplish what asked in the post. Thx anyway :)

Comment: @user846226 in css you cannot select by parent, so your requirement to select elements whose "`parent is not xxx`" is unfortunately impossible, quite apart from the issue with the `not` selector.

Comment: @nvioli, i disagree. you could use ":not(ul) > a" to select anchors whose parents are not ul elements.